# calculate average with a dynamic filter

Tags: powerbi

I have a set of data that looks something like the attached, I would like to create a matrix that allows me to calculate the average size by the number of months selected. For example, if the filter is set on Jan and Feb, the average for city abc would be zone 1 (848) and zone 2 (306). TIA

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated after your comment:

Given a table called Sheet1 such as this:
[image]

1. Create a New Measure to calculate the quantity of months between the first month and the last one. If you have one entry per months this should work:

[image]

```
Months =  
var MonthStart = CALCULATE(Year(FIRSTDATE(Sheet1[month]))*12+Month(FIRSTDATE(Sheet1[month])),ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[month]))   
var MonthEnd = cALCULATE(Year(LASTDATE(Sheet1[month]))*12+Month(LASTDATE(Sheet1[month])),ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[month]))
RETURN
MonthEnd-MonthStart+1
```

2. Create a New Measure to sum over all values and divide it by the [Months] measure.

   TotalAmount = sum(Sheet1[size])/[Months]

This should yield the results:
[image]

Comment: This method gives me the average of each records, I need the average per number of months selected.